# Replace sterr message by string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm looking for a way to log crontable events. thus by writing in a log file the date of execution and the result. for example

```
Tue Feb 14 11:17:01 CET 2017 Finish with success
Tue Feb 14 11:18:01 CET 2017 Finish with errors
```

So for the first one i've found a way to do it. By this way:

```
0,5,10,15 * * * * /path/to/script  $args  2>>  /path/to/logFile.log && echo "$(date) Finish with success" >>  /path/to/logFile.log
```

So when there's an error I don't know how to replace the error output by the string "$(date) Finish with errors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the log on failure condition with the Boolean `||` operator which executes on failure of the command,

```
0,5,10,15 * * * * /path/to/script "$args" >> /path/to/logFile.log 2>/dev/null && echo "$(date) Finish with success" >>  /path/to/logFile.log \
  || echo "$(date) Finish with errors" >>  /path/to/logFile.log
```

Append `stdout` to file and `stderr` to `NULL` as `>> /path/to/logFile.log 2>/dev/null`

Comment: This almost answer to my question to only issue is that it still prints the error output of the script. which is not what I want... I actually only want it to print the string $(date) finish with error...

Comment: @JoeyPablo: You want to suppress error output from written to the log?

Comment: @indian yes, i only want to know if there was an error or not. I don't want to see the details of the error.

Comment: @JoeyPablo: Refer my update! which takes care of that