# Add date as prefix to stderr & stdout

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this shell code that is executed in a crontable.

```
/path/to/script args >> /path/logfile 2>> test.txt && echo "$(date) success" >>  /path/logfile || echo "$(date) errors" >>  /path/logfile
```

It writes in a logfile which is formated in this way:

```
STDOUT
DATE success
STDERROR
DATE errors
```

Actually i'm trying since hours ago to format it this way but I didn't succeed...

```
DATE success: stdout (without newlines)
DATE errors: stderr (without newlines)
```

Comment: The `\\` is a just a line separator, remove it from the command.

Comment: Also controlling how your script writes to `stdout`, should be more controlled (if possible) from the script itself and not outside.

Comment: The \ is not a line separator. It is just starts an escape sequence if not at the very end of the line. At the end of the line it interpreted as a continuation character

Comment: @Inian it is controlled, actually i'm just trying to format the log file in a readable way. thank u

Comment: @Inian as I explained the stderr & stdout is written before the timestamp; i'd like to write it after

Comment: @hek2mgl: I know that for a fact, The reason I mentioned it was from my answer to OP's earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/a/42223691/5291015, used `\\` as continuation character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script an easy solution:

```
/path/to/script args >/path/tmp/log.out 2>/path/tmp/log.err
if [ ! -s  /path/tmp/log.err ]; then
   echo -n "$(date) success: " >> /path/logfile
   cat /path/tmp/log.out >> /path/logfile
else
   echo -n "$(date) errors: " >> /path/logfile
   cat /path/tmp/log.err >> /path/logfile
fi
```

Comment: thanks for answering but avoiding the newlines isn't the real problem;

Comment: I want to print the $(date) before the outputs. for now it prints the outputs and then the date

Comment: really ? I thought it was just an ordering question... the scenario is ( if the exit code is 2 then i'll print $date errors: stderror else $date success: stdout ) I'm not very familiar with shell so I don't know how to do this

Comment: Cheers @JoeyPablo